# django extending an app to allow non authenticated votes

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-authentication, django-voting

I have been testing a few django voting apps and found `qhonuskan-votes`. I have managed to install it and is works great. However, I also want it allow voting rights to non authenticated users which I am not able to do. Need help with this please.

`Here is the link for its models.py, views.py and compact.py files of this app.`

[models](http://paste.ofcode.org/K6YeqV3jSNsUtr65t6aNxf)

[views](http://paste.ofcode.org/3aGMNxQu9arNmxncNBZJ5Eb)

[compact](http://paste.ofcode.org/seL2WEMdzPcLUBcSSUzguX)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom view which would look like *def vote(request, model, object_id, value)* from the external app, but without this piece of code in it:

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponse(status=401)
```

Also make sure, that you map your custom view to the correct url instead of including app's urls:

```
url(r'^vote/$', view='custom_vote', name='qhonuskan_vote'))
```

This is not the best solution, because you are simply rewriting the code from the external app and I can't think of any proper way to override the default view in a way that would suit your needs. A better solution would be to use a different app, which allows votes by unauthenticated users (if a few lines of additional code are not a problem you can use this).